# Is it possible to claim a custom AWS ELB subdomain which has no associated A/CNAME records

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

Example : something-307931401.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com

Is there a way to get this specific ELB domain for my load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. You cannot reserve your "myelbinstance.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com".

Using Route53, you can point a domain (or a subdomain) to your ELB instance and then use: my-balancer.my-domain.com

**Have a look at the documentation:**

> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-domain-names-with-elb.html#dns-associate-custom-elb